# Combine tkinter and turtle, alarm clock python.

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, python-datetime

I have made this alarm clock but can't seem to combine my turtle graphics with tkinder at least not all of it. Additionally I can't seem to get my alarm to respond to imputed date time.

## alarm clock

```
import winsound
import turtle
from turtle import *
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

#combine turtle and tkinder    
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Alarm Clock")
      
cv = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=700, height=700)
cv.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)

sc = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
sc.setpos(0, -200)
       
s = sc.getscreen()
s.delay(0)
#turtle draws a circle
for aColor in ["black", "black", "black", "black"]:
               
        sc.color(aColor)
        sc.pensize(3)
               
        def drawPoly(t, num_sides, side_length):
                for i in range(num_sides):
                    t.forward(side_length)
                    t.left(90 / num_sides)
        drawPoly(sc, 320, 1)
sc.color("white")
sc.fd(100)  
      
def jump(distanz, winkel=0):
        penup()
        right(winkel)
        forward(distanz)
        left(winkel)
        pendown()

def hand(laenge, spitze):
        fd(laenge*1.10)
        rt(90)
        fd(spitze/20.0)
        lt(120)
        fd(spitze)
        lt(120)
        fd(spitze)
        lt(120)
        fd(spitze/20.0)

def make_hand_shape(name, laenge, spitze):
        reset()
        jump(-laenge*0.15)
        begin_poly()
        hand(laenge, spitze)
        end_poly()
        hand_form = get_poly()
        register_shape(name, hand_form)

def clockface(radius):
        
        reset()
        pencolor("black")
        pensize(7)
        for i in range(60):
                jump(radius)
                if i % 5 == 0:
                        fd(25)
                        jump(-radius-25)
                else:
                        dot(4)
                        jump(-radius)
                rt(6)
        
def setup():
        global second_hand, minute_hand, hour_hand, sc
        mode("logo")
        #clock hands    
        make_hand_shape("second_hand", 125, 5)
        make_hand_shape("minute_hand",  130, 5)
        make_hand_shape("hour_hand", 90, 5)
        clockface(160)

        second_hand = Turtle()
        second_hand.shape("second_hand")
        second_hand.color("grey", "grey")
            
        minute_hand = Turtle()
        minute_hand.shape("minute_hand")
        minute_hand.color("#505050", "#505050")
            
        hour_hand = Turtle()
        hour_hand.shape("hour_hand")
        hour_hand.color("#191919", "#191919")
            
        for hand in second_hand, minute_hand, hour_hand:
                hand.resizemode("user")
                hand.shapesize(1, 1, 3)
                hand.speed(0)
                ht()
        
        sc.ht()
        sc.pu()
        sc.bk(85)

def wochentag(t):
        wochentag = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        return wochentag[t.weekday()]
#date
def datum(z):
        monat = ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "June",
                     "July", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."]
        j = z.year
        m = monat[z.month - 1]
        t = z.day
        return "%s %d %d" % (m, t, j)

def tick():
        t = datetime.today()
        sekunde = t.second + t.microsecond*0.000001
        minute = t.minute + sekunde/60.0
        stunde = t.hour + minute/60.0
        try:
                tracer(False)  # Terminator can occur here
                
                sc.setpos(0, 100)
                sc.clear()
                sc.home()
                sc.forward(65)
                sc.pencolor("grey")
                sc.write(wochentag(t),
                                align="center", font=("Courier", 14, "bold"))
                sc.back(150)
                sc.write(datum(t),
                                align="center", font=("Courier", 14, "bold"))
                sc.goto(-20, 200)
                d = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
                current_time = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
                sc.write(current_time,
                         align="center", font=("Courier", 14, "bold"))

                tracer(True)
                second_hand.setheading(6*sekunde)  # or here
                minute_hand.setheading(6*minute)
                hour_hand.setheading(30*stunde)
                tracer(True)
                ontimer(tick, 100)
        except Terminator:
                pass 
        
def main():
        tracer(False)
        setup()
        tracer(True)
        tick()
        return "EVENTLOOP"
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
        mode("logo")
        main()
        
d = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
current_time = (datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"))   
print (datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"))
 
#combine turtle and tkinder
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT,fill=tkinter.BOTH)

pointLabel = tkinter.Label(frame,text="Set Alarm")
pointLabel.pack()

#button sets imputed time and date for alarm to start
pointSize = tkinter.StringVar()
pointEntry = tkinter.Entry(frame,textvariable=pointSize)
pointEntry.pack()
pointSize.set(current_time)

alarm_clock_dic = []

def quitHandler():       
        alarm_clock_dic.append(pointSize)

cmd_Button = tkinter.Button(frame, text = "Enter Time", command=quitHandler, 
bg ='grey', fg = 'white')
cmd_Button.pack()

if alarm_clock_dic == (current_time):
        winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_LOOP)
        winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_LOOP)
        winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_LOOP)
        winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_LOOP)
        winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_LOOP)

mainloop()
```

Need help fast!

Answer (score 0):

> I ... can't seem to combine my turtle graphics with tkinder

My recommendation is you toss the tkinter part and do this completely with turtle.  You only seem to need tkinter for the alarm setting which I've redone below using a turtle as a button and the `textinput(title, prompt)` function introduced in Python 3 (I've also reworked your code a bit):

```
# import winsound
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Terminator
from datetime import datetime

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')
screen.setup(700, 700)
screen.title('Alarm Clock')

wochentag_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
monat = ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.']

FONT_SIZE = 14
FONT = ('Courier', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')
BUTTON_SIZE = 40
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def jump(turtle, distanz):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(distanz)
    turtle.pendown()

def hand(turtle, laenge, spitze):
    turtle.fd(laenge * 1.10)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.fd(spitze / 20.0)
    turtle.lt(120)
    turtle.fd(spitze)
    turtle.lt(120)
    turtle.fd(spitze)
    turtle.lt(120)
    turtle.fd(spitze / 20.0)

def make_hand_shape(turtle, name, laenge, spitze):
    turtle.reset()
    jump(turtle, -laenge * 0.15)
    turtle.begin_poly()
    hand(turtle, laenge, spitze)
    turtle.end_poly()
    screen.register_shape(name, turtle.get_poly())

def clockface(radius):
    face = Turtle()
    face.pensize(3)
    face.speed('fastest')

    jump(face, radius)
    face.left(90)
    face.circle(radius)
    face.right(90)
    jump(face, -radius)
    face.pensize(7)

    radius *= 0.8

    jump(face, radius)

    for i in range(60):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            face.forward(25)
            jump(face, -25)
        else:
            face.dot(4)

        face.left(90)
        face.penup()
        face.circle(radius, 6)
        face.pendown()
        face.right(90)

    face.hideturtle()

def setup():
    hand = Turtle()

    # clock hands
    make_hand_shape(hand, 'second_hand', 125, 5)
    make_hand_shape(hand, 'minute_hand', 130, 5)
    make_hand_shape(hand, 'hour_hand', 90, 5)

    hand.reset()
    hand.hideturtle()

    clockface(200)

    second_hand = Turtle()
    second_hand.shape('second_hand')
    second_hand.color('grey')

    minute_hand = Turtle()
    minute_hand.shape('minute_hand')
    minute_hand.color('#505050')

    hour_hand = Turtle()
    hour_hand.shape('hour_hand')
    hour_hand.color('#191919')

    for hand in second_hand, minute_hand, hour_hand:
        hand.shapesize(outline=3)
        hand.speed('fastest')

    return second_hand, minute_hand, hour_hand

def wochentag(t):
    return wochentag_list[t.weekday()]
# date
def datum(z):
    j = z.year
    m = monat[z.month - 1]
    t = z.day

    return '%s %d %d' % (m, t, j)

def tick():

    t = datetime.today()

    sekunde = t.second + t.microsecond * 0.000001
    minute = t.minute + sekunde / 60.0
    stunde = t.hour + minute / 60.0

    d = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    current_time = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')

    try:
        marker1.undo()
        marker1.write(wochentag(t), align='center', font=FONT)

        marker2.undo()
        marker2.write(datum(t), align='center', font=FONT)

        marker3.undo()
        marker3.write(current_time, align='center', font=FONT)

        second_hand.setheading(6 * sekunde)
        minute_hand.setheading(6 * minute)
        hour_hand.setheading(30 * stunde)

        screen.update()

        if current_time in alarm_clock_dic:
            #winsound.PlaySound('SystemExit', winsound.SND_LOOP)
            #winsound.PlaySound('SystemExit', winsound.SND_LOOP)
            #winsound.PlaySound('SystemExit', winsound.SND_LOOP)
            #winsound.PlaySound('SystemExit', winsound.SND_LOOP)
            #winsound.PlaySound('SystemExit', winsound.SND_LOOP)
            pass

        screen.ontimer(tick, 100)
    except Terminator:
        screen.bye()

def set_alarm(x, y):
    d = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    current_time = (datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'))

    pointSize = screen.textinput(current_time, "Enter Time")
    alarm_clock_dic.append(pointSize)

marker1 = Turtle(visible=False)
marker1.penup()
marker1.forward(65)
marker1.color('grey')
marker1.write('', align='center', font=FONT)

marker2 = Turtle(visible=False)
marker2.penup()
marker2.backward(85)
marker2.color('grey')
marker2.write('', align='center', font=FONT)

marker3 = Turtle(visible=False)
marker3.penup()
marker3.goto(0, 220)
marker3.color('grey')
marker3.write('', align='center', font=FONT)

screen.tracer(False)
second_hand, minute_hand, hour_hand = setup()

button = Turtle('circle')
button.shapesize(BUTTON_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=2)
button.color('black', 'red')
button.penup()
button.goto(250, 250)  # move the button into position

marker4 = Turtle(visible=False)
marker4.penup()
marker4.goto(button.xcor(), button.ycor() - BUTTON_SIZE/2 - FONT_SIZE - 2)
marker4.write('Set Alarm', align='center', font=FONT)

screen.update()

alarm_clock_dic = []

button.onclick(set_alarm)

tick()

screen.mainloop()
```

> I can't seem to get my alarm to respond to imputed date time

I've hinted at how this might work in my code design but I haven't tested it.  I don't have the winsound library which is why I've commented out the winsound related code -- there's nothing wrong with it that I know.

[image]